# Velocity Template - Exception in thread "main" org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource

Tags: java, templates, resources, velocity

I have tried running simple velocity template program in java eclipse and getting below error:

```
Sep 22, 2017 4:53:14 PM org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute log
SEVERE: ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'templates/HelloWorld.vm' in any resource loader.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'templates/HelloWorld.vm'
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1533)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1514)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.getTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:373)
    at com.sapient.velocity.HelloVelocity.main(HelloVelocity.java:18)
```

tried everything checking errors online stackoverflow:

my project structure:

[image]

`HelloWorld.vm`:

```
Velocity Template $helloWorld

HelloVelocity Class

public class HelloVelocity {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
        ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
        ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
        ve.init();
        Template t = ve.getTemplate("templates/HelloWorld.vm");
        VelocityContext vc = new VelocityContext();
        vc.put("helloWorld", "Hello World!!!");
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        t.merge(vc, sw);
        System.out.println(sw);
    }
}
```

I am using Velocity 1.7 build.

Answer (score 2):

Rename the file `HelloWorld.vm` in your resource folder instead of `HelloWold.vm` .
There is a mismatch in the filename.

Comment: hi one more help.. I want to generate sql source code using Velocity template language (vtl) giving user input on the columns and where clause criteria on a preknown query. Can you please help me with the design of code for generating sql query based on user input from vtl.

Comment: Hi Pulkit please raise another question or update your question with clear requirement so that it would be easy to understand and answer